# R sum rows of matrix by column name

Tags: r, matrix

This seems like it should be easy but I can't figure it out.  I would like to sum all of the columns of my matrix that have the same name.  So, in the example below, I would like to end up with another matrix with only three columns.

```
set.seed(4)
z<-matrix(sample(1:10,20, replace=T), nrow=4)
colnames(z)<-c("a","c","b","a","b")
z
     a  c  b  a  b
[1,] 6  9 10  2 10
[2,] 1  3  1 10  6
[3,] 3  8  8  5 10
[4,] 3 10  3  5  8
```

should yield:

```
     a  c  b
[1,] 8  9 20
[2,] 11  3  7
[3,] 8  8  18
[4,] 8 10  11
```

I tried:

```
z<-aggregate(colnames(z), data=z, sum)
```

but it did not work.  I would prefer to use base R if possible.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `rowsum` with the column names as `group` variable:

```
t(rowsum(t(z), colnames(z)))

#      a  b  c
#[1,]  8 20  9
#[2,] 11  7  3
#[3,]  8 18  8
#[4,]  8 11 10
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
sapply(unique(colnames(z)), function(x) rowSums(z[, colnames(z)==x, drop=FALSE]))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option using `xtabs`

```
library(reshape2)
xtabs(value~Var1 +Var2, melt(z))
#    Var2
#Var1  a  c  b
#   1  8  9 20
#   2 11  3  7
#   3  8  8 18
#   4  8 10 11
```

---

Or with `tapply`

```
tapply(z, list(row(z), colnames(z)[col(z)]), FUN = sum)
#    a  b  c
# 1  8 20  9
# 2 11  7  3
#3  8 18  8
#4  8 11 10
```

Answer (score 0):

This will also do.

```
set.seed(4)
z<-matrix(sample(1:10,20, replace=T), nrow=4)
colnames(z)<-c("a","c","b","a","b")
z <- as.data.table(z)
z[,id:=.I]
z <- melt(z,id.vars="id")
z[,sum:=sum(value),by=.(variable,id)]
z[,value:=NULL]
z <- dcast.data.table(z, id~variable,value.var = "sum", fun.aggregate = max)
z[,id:=NULL]
```

Resulting in

```
    a  c  b
1:  8  9 20
2: 11  3  7
3:  8  8 18
4:  8 10 11
```